# Text Editor Works in <textarea> but not when displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very, very complex issue here and I wonder if you can help.

I have a blog system where I use a form to create a blog post. Here's what the form looks like: http://prntscr.com/7wupnn (As you can see, I've made a bit bold and changed the colour).

Here's the source of that form:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('db_connect.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
header('Location: login.php');
exit();
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$title = $db->real_escape_string($title);
$body = $db->real_escape_string($body);
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
$body = htmlentities($body);
if($title && $body && $category){
$query = $db->query("INSERT INTO posts (user_id, title, body, category_id, posted) VALUES('$user_id', '$title', '$body', '$category', '$date')");
if($query){
echo '<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 40px; left: 500px; padding: 10px; background: red; box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000; color: #fff;">Post Added</div>';
}else{
echo '<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 40px; left: 500px; padding: 10px; background: red; box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000; color: #fff;">An unexpected error has occured.</div>';
}
}else{
echo '<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 40px; left: 500px; padding: 10px; background: red; box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000; color: #fff;">Please enter all the required information to proceed</div>';
}
}
?>


<div id="mainbox">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Post Title Here">
<p></p>
<textarea name="body" id="mytextarea" cols=50 rows=10 placeholder="Enter Post Content Here"></textarea>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'mytextarea' );
</script>
<p></p>
<input type="file" name="upfile">
<select name="category">
<?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories");
while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
echo "<option value='".$row->category_id."'>".$row->category."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<p></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

When I click submit, the post is then published onto the blog page - however it's lost all it's style - here's what I mean: http://prntscr.com/7wuq9f - as you can see, the browser is displaying the HTML rather than using it.

Here's the code for he blog page:

```
<?php
include('blog/db_connect.php');
$record_count = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts");
$per_page = 2;
$pages = ceil($record_count->num_rows/$per_page);
if(isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])){
$page = $_GET['p'];
}else{
$page = 1;
}
if($page<=0)
$start = 0;
else
$start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, LEFT(body, 100) AS body, category FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=posts.category_id order by post_id desc limit $start, $per_page");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $body, $category);
?>

<div id="mainbox">
<?php
while($query->fetch()):
$html_body = nl2br($body);
$lastspace = strrpos($html_body, ' ');
?>
<h2><?php echo $title?></h2>
<p><?php echo substr($html_body, 0, $lastspace)."<a href='blog/post.php?id=$post_id'>..</a>"?></p>
<p>Category: <?php echo $category?>
<hr />
<p></p>
<?php endwhile?>

<?php
if($prev > 0){
echo "<a href='blog.php?p=$prev'>Previous Page</a>";
}
if($page < $pages){
echo "<a href='blog.php?p=$next'>Next Page</a>";
}
?>

</div>
```

Instructions on how to keep the style of the text when publishing it would be appreciated.

Comment: check CKEditor config is set to not strip inline style

Comment: Anyone else got a suggestion?

Comment: You are using htmlentities ... do you ever decode it for output? There's your issue. Look at the current html in a textarea with no CKEditor will see exactly what's going on

Comment: I don't get what you mean..

Comment: if you don't get it look at what htmlentites does in the manual

Comment: so what do i need to do? could you give me a code example please

Comment: look at the php manual... shows you the related method

Answer (score 0):

`substr($html_body, 0, $lastspace)` is truncating your `HTML`.

And incomplete `HTML` won't get rendered.

Why are you doing this?

**Don't do `substr($html_body, 0, $lastspace)`.**

Just `echo $html_body`

Comment: What do you recommend changing it to?

Comment: Just `echo $html_body`

Comment: How is it displaying after making the changes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84268/discussion-between-shrinivas-shukla-and-jugglingbob).